# Как заблокировать элемент до его появление?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть скрипт, который отвечает за вывод попап окна. Появляется оно при клике на блок, и анимация идет 1s. Так же сделал, что при клике на пустое пространство окно исчезает. Все хорошо работает, только если пользователь нажмет случайно два раза по блоку либо один раз по блоку и в течение пока окно появляется нажмет еще один раз, то блок появиться и сразу исчезает. Мне посоветовали "Можно блокировать скрипт пока она не появиться до конца".
Вопрос, как это сделать?

```
$('.auth-login__yes').on('click',function(){
  $('.login-user').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
  var div = $(".login-user"); // тут указываем ID элемента
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
      && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
    div.hide("slide", {direction: "left"} , 1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняйте информацию о загрузке окна в переменной или в самом объекте с помощью функции [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('.auth-login__yes').on('click',function(){

  var $loginUser = $('.login-user'); // сохраним попап в переменную

  if ($loginUser.data('loading')) return; // если уже загружается, ничего не делаем

  $loginUser
    .data('loading', true) // указываем, что попап загружается
    .show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function () {
      $(this).data('loading', false) // попап загрузился
    });
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
  var div = $(".login-user"); // тут указываем ID элемента

  if (div.data('loading')) return; // если загружается, ничего не делаем

  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
      && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
    div.hide("slide", {direction: "left"} , 1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Распространенный вариант: когда вы ожидаете выполнения чего-то (в данном случае загрузка диалога), надо показать поверх всего иконку загрузки. После выполнения необходимых вещей (диалог загрузился) - вы убираете иконку.

Это может быть не просто иконка, а блок размером с окно поверх всего остального, чтобы повторные клики были на нем, а не на функциональных элементах, что поможет избежать двойного нажатия и прочих вещей.